# Expand Safe dashboard from within a SafeApp

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is it possible to trigger the Safe dashboards 'Transaction queue' accordion to expand from within a SafeApp?

After a user has signed, I want to be able to trigger the transaction queue to appear with the transaction details.

[image: Transaction queue expanded]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation of the transaction queue at the bottom doesn't support a way to interface with it from within a safe app.

Comment: In my UI, when the user has signed, I want to give the user an option to click a button that will automatically open/expand/slide-up the 'Transaction queue' section and highlight a specific safeTxHash, while still maintaining my session in the SafeApp behind.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The current implementation of the transaction queue at the bottom doesn't support a way to interface with it from within a safe app but it is an interesting idea! I would suggest submitting an issue in the web-core repository.